# How do I stop Seahorse from asking for my password multiple times on every login?

Tags: 11.04, login, seahorse

I've set up my System to log me in automatically but for some reason I need to "unlock my keyring" x times, where x is a number much larger than one. I've read a few similar threads here and elsewhere but I've yet to find a solution to the problem.

How do I stop this from happening?

[image: Seahorse screenshot]Seahorse screenshot

**Note** : The original title described the behaviour as "molestation" which I think is apt.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your default keyring and change its password to nothing.

Comment: Isn't that "unsafe"?

Comment: yes - but you've already accepted the risk by using automatic login.  If you use standard login, the keyring wouldnt be an issue.

Comment: So I need to either have zero protection for my passwords and other stuff or disable autologin? I thought the keyring was supposed to work like keepassx. Ie. you have one password that unlocks all the others. Just one pass after i get autologgedin. That would be great.

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me. My answer is just a workaround. You're right, it shouldn't be doing this in the first place.